# Awkward holes in drywall—patch or replace?

Tags: patching-drywall

There are rectangular doglegs cut out in the drywall pictured below. Should I cut patches to fit, or cut out a large rectangle and replace it all?

I have lumber and access is easy, so I can easily put a piece of 2x4 there to attach the patches to.

It’s likely that a television screen will be going in front of it.

My experience with drywall installation and patching is minimal.

[image: https://imgur.com/a/JVuQ9mM]

Comment: I agreed with @ecnerwal that expanding and getting rid of the dog legs will be much easier, even with cutting the outlet boxes in. It will make taping it easier. One thing to consider, paper tape can be a challenge when first starting out and it tends to bubble if not bedded correctly, I would encourage you to use something like Fibafuse, it is perfect for this application.

Comment: If putting a TV/entertainment center there you might put in a larger electrical box and have 4 outlets available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's usually easiest to cut the place to be patched larger (including half-a-stud exposed on the edge, and making the needed cutouts for the electrical boxes in the patch) than to fiddle with small bits, if the larger patch is smaller than or equal to a full sheet of drywall.

Less total length of seam to tape and mud.